# How can I refresh a javascript file that has already been loaded once a div is generated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page which contains a hype document, which is a sequence of animations played as scenes.  In the final scene a green tick is generated allowing the user to move onto the next chapter.  I want the green tick to show its tooltip as designated by a javascript file tooltip.js.  This file is loaded with the page as it used on other elements within the page outside the hype element.

The problem is that as tooltip.js is loaded with the page before the green tick has been generated, it does not apply itself to the green tick.  I can get round this by:

```
if (scenenumber3 == finalSceneNumber) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = "/scripts/tooltip.js"
    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Where scenenumber3 is the current scene number, so on the final scene where the green tick is generated the tooltip.js is added and loaded.  This works but means the tooltip.js file is loaded every time that scene is run.  It also means this file clashes with the originally loaded file, causing some problems.  The tooltip.js file is as follows:

```
$(function ()
{
    var targets = $( '[data-rel~=tooltip]' ),
        target  = false,
        tooltip = false,
        title   = false;

targets.bind('mouseenter', function ()
{
    target  = $( this );
    tip     = target.attr( 'title' );
    tooltip = $( '<div id="tooltip"></div>' );

    if( !tip || tip == '' )
        return false;

    target.removeAttr( 'title' );
    tooltip.css( 'opacity', 0 )
           .html( tip )
           .appendTo( 'body' );

    var init_tooltip = function ()
    {
        if( $( window ).width() < tooltip.outerWidth() * 1.5 )
            tooltip.css( 'max-width', $( window ).width() / 2 );
        else
            tooltip.css( 'max-width', 340 );

        var pos_left = target.offset().left + ( target.outerWidth() / 2 ) - ( tooltip.outerWidth() / 2 ),
            pos_top  = target.offset().top - tooltip.outerHeight() - 8;

        if( pos_left < 0 )
        {
            pos_left = target.offset().left + target.outerWidth() / 2 - 8;
            tooltip.addClass( 'left' );
        }
        else
            tooltip.removeClass( 'left' );

        if( pos_left + tooltip.outerWidth() > $( window ).width() )
        {
            pos_left = target.offset().left - tooltip.outerWidth() + target.outerWidth() / 2 + 20;
            tooltip.addClass( 'right' );
        }
        else
            tooltip.removeClass( 'right' );

        if( pos_top < 0 )
        {
            var pos_top  = target.offset().top + target.outerHeight();
            tooltip.addClass( 'top' );
        }
        else
            tooltip.removeClass( 'top' );

        tooltip.css( { left: pos_left, top: pos_top } )
               .animate( { top: '+=0', opacity: 1 }, 250 );
    };

    init_tooltip();
    $( window ).resize( init_tooltip );

    var remove_tooltip = function ()
    {
        tooltip.animate({ top: '-=0', opacity: 0 }, 250, function ()
        {
            $( this ).remove();
        });

        target.attr( 'title', tip );
    };

    target.bind( 'mouseleave', remove_tooltip );
    tooltip.bind( 'click', remove_tooltip );
});
```

What I would like to know is what is the best way to handle this?  Can I re-run the tooltip.js file that has already been loaded so it applies to the green tick only?  I'm not in any way experienced with javascript so I would appreciate hearing what those who know javascript well would do to handle this situation?

Comment: Ideally your tooltip function is "triggered" by a function call of some variety. So rather than appending the script at the right time, instead you'd already have the script loaded, and then trigger it to run with something like `$('[data-rel~="tooltip"]).tooltip();` to cause the script to then apply the tooltips to those elements.

Comment: as the above commenter said, wrap it all in a function that you can call anytime. Load the file once at page load using a script tag, then call the function when you need to. That's how 99.9999% of all the JS libraries in the world work. Your implementation is odd and creating you a problem you can easily avoid.

Comment: The issue you describe is just 'bad design' in my humble opinion. Tool tips can be done fully in css using the :hover pseudoclass, which enables you to put all the tooltips inside the html of that page. If you do want/need to use javascript for the tooltips, save all the tooltips in the same script together with a reference to which chapter the tooltip belongs. Then you can pull any tooltip out of that array or object without the need to load more javascript.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, they have set me on the right track.